# Integer.parseInt removes leading 0

Tags: java, parseint, leading-zero

My program is asking for the time and I am splitting the time by the `":"`. For some reason if I input something with a `0` before as the first value, it removes it. Any idea why it does this?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrivalTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean rushHour;

        System.out.print("Enter The Time Fiona Will Leave For Work (HH:MM): ");
        String departureTime = sc.nextLine();

        String parts[] = departureTime.split(":");

        int departureHour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int departureMinute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        System.out.println(departureHour + " " + departureMinute);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("00")` returns integer value represented by `0`. What exactly did you expect and why? Why not use Strings `parts[0]` `parts[1]` directly instead of int?

Comment: Use formatted output (if you want `00`). Like, `System.out.printf("%02d:%02d%n", departureHour, departureMinute);`

Comment: “Removes leading zeros" is strictly speaking an incorrect description. `parseInt()` gives you a Java `int`, and an `int` doesn’t have leading zeroes in this sense (behind the scenes it’s 32 bits binary and usually has leading zero bits, but that’s a completely different story). You will have to learn that the *value* of an `int` is just a number, and the *way it is printed* is something else: any `int` value can be displayed with or without any number of leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

```
int departureHour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int departureMinute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
System.out.println(departureHour + " " + departureMinute);
```

`Integer.parseInt(ANY_INTEGER_VALUE)` returns integer. e.g. `Integer.parseInt(03)` will return 3 instead of 03.

If you want to display the given input

> 03:09

as it is, you should keep the String displayed as it is:

```
System.out.println (parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
```

Parse to int for calculation purposes only.

**Note: I have edited the below part after reading @Elliot's comment.**

Or as @Elliot specified in his comment:

```
System.out.printf("%02d %02d%n", departureHour, departureMinute);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `Integer.parseInt()` call. When you pass there some String with leading zeros they will be removed and the result is a natural number. If you want to see the leading zeros just write:

```
String departureHour = parts[0];
String departureMinute = parts[1];

System.out.println(departureHour + " " + departureMinute);
```